# Change color of money in HTML (using javascript/regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to change the color of currency (only USD $ symbol is fine) given a string, and this would be later put in the DOM. For example inputting

```
colorMoney("I have $100 in my bank account right now");
```

would return the string

```
"I have <span class='accent'>$100</span> in my bank account right now"
```

and then I'd style `.accent` with CSS. The Regex I have so far is

```
/\$[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*/
```

The matches any amount of money (including with a decimal), now I need a way to wrap in in `<span>`s without deleting the number.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `replace()`.

Comment: Yes, but how would I keep the amount after the $ symbol too? Not just replacing the `$` with `<span>`

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), specifically the `$1` placeholders.

Comment: Figured it out, here's the code if anyone else stumbles upon this (won't let me post as answer for some reason): `"I have $100".replace(/\$[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*/, "<span class=\"accent\">$&</span>")`

Answer (score 0):

With help from tadman, using string.replace with placeholders can get this working:

```js
const myString = "I have $100 right now";
console.log(myString.replace(/\$[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*/, "<span class=\"accent\">$&</span>"));
```

Comment: Add a `g` flag to the regex, so that more than one dollar number is highlighted.